# Centring an image when margin:0 auto; and absolute positioning doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to centre most of the images in this page, all the ones I need to centre are of class `.loadMeLater`.

The image is a loading spinner placeholder and then the real image is loaded when it appears in the viewport.
I want the placeholder and the real image to be centred. They are both in the same element, which has the class `.loadMeLater`.

I tried `margin:0 auto` and that doesn't work, I can't use absolute positioning and `left:0` and `right:0` because that causes the image's container to be too small.

Currently I'm centring the spinner with relative positioning, `left:50%`, and `margin-left:-0.5*spinner-width;`
And I am centring the image using a calculation in javascript involving the width of the image and the parent.

**There has to be an easier way to centre the image. Anyone have any ideas how to do so?**

Here is the site: http://irfandesign.com/dev/

To show the elements that have the images, click on ' learn more about me ' or ' work '. Then scroll down to them.

Comment: shared link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Try just

```
margin:auto;
```

I'm not sure if what you have is actually a valid implementation.

Comment: how is it not a valid implementation?

Comment: having
    margin:0 auto;
is redundant; you are saying 'have a margin of zero, but also have it automatically fit'

Answer (score 0):

By default an img tag has 'display: inline-block;'

if you select your img tag and do this:

```
img {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It will center your image within its container div